# Bits needed to change one number to another

Tags: c#, c++, c, algorithm

Say I have two positive numbers a and b. How many bits must be inverted in order to convert a into b ?
I just want the count and not the exact position of the differing bits.

Lets assume a = 10 ( 1010 ) and b = 8 ( 1000 ). In this case the number of bits that should be inverted equals 1.

Any generalised algorithm?

Comment: You possibly already know it but for the record, this thing is called Hamming distance.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The solution is simple

- Step 1 ) Compute a [XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) b
- Step 2 ) [Count the number of set bits in the result](http://www-graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetNaive)

Done!

Comment: I agree that this is *a* correct answer, however the OP asks for a generalised algorithm. "Count the number of set bits in the result" would be too high-level an instruction to qualify as a step in an algorithm. I'm not sure if this answer is 20 upvotes better than the others.

Comment: It's a perfect answer. Some CPUs have even population count as a single instruction, at least used to, because it has applications in cryptography.

Comment: Your second and most important step has a broken link.  This answer is incomplete and a perfect example of why you should bring the code.

Answer (score 7):

```
int a = 10;
int b = 8;

int c = a ^ b; //xor
int count = 0;
while (c != 0)
{
  if ((c & 1) != 0)
    count++;
  c = c >> 1;
}
return count;
```

Comment: Note that there are usually faster methods of getting the population count of a number. I read a nice article on it in 'Beautiful code'

Answer (score 2):

```
changeMask = a XOR b
bitsToChange = 0
while changeMask>0
  bitsToChange = bitsToChange + (changeMask AND 1)
  changeMask = changeMask >> 1
loop
return bitsToChange
```

Answer (score 1):

Good old-fashioned bit operations!

```
size_t countbits( unsigned int n )
{
   size_t bits = 0;
   while( n )
   {
      bits += n&1;
      n >>= 1;
   }
   return bits;
}

countbits( a ^ b );
```

This could would work in C as well as C++. You could (in C++ only) make the countbits function a template.

Answer (score -1):

Actually,humbly building on previous answer -  this might work better for converting a to b:

the only difference with previous answer is that the bits already set in b dont need to be set again - so dont count them.

calculate (a XOR b) AND ~b

count the set bits

post corrected as per comment. Thanks!

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re alluding to with the set bits, but your answer is certainly wrong. The OP wants to calculate the Hamming distance between the two bit strings and the previous answers do this correctly. Your `AND !b` would yield a different result (apart from the set that you probably mean `~b` instead of `!b` to invert the bits).

Answer (score -2):

abs(popcount(a) - popcount(b)) where popcount counts bits set in number (a lot of different variants exists)

Comment: This is wrong.  If the inputs are (binary) 0101 and 1010 it will return 0, but the correct answer is 4.

Comment: Yep, I misunderstood the question :)